# How do I print the values of instance variables for each instance of a class?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking to print out the name and status variables for each instance of the FamilyMember class. I've created the instances and added them to an array. When I attempt to loop through the array using the .each method the name and status variables are not recoignised. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class FamilyMember
  attr_reader :name, :age, :sex, :status, :country



  def initialize (name, age, sex, status, country)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @sex = sex
    @status = status
    @country = country

  end

  def parent?

  end

  def child?

  end
end
```

## Instances of the class

```
fm1 = FamilyMember.new('Scott', 18 , 'Male', 'Employed', 'America'),
fm2 = FamilyMember.new('Stephen', 30, 'Male', 'Employed', 'Ireland'),
fm3 = FamilyMember.new('Gillian', 50, 'Female', 'Employed', 'Ireland'),
fm4 = FamilyMember.new('Rolf', 56, 'Male', 'Employed', 'Ireland'),
fm5 = FamilyMember.new('Shane', 14, 'Male', 'Unemployed', 'Ireland')
```

## Creating array

```
array_1 = Array.new
```

## Adding elements to the array

```
array_1 << fm1
array_1 << fm2
array_1 << fm3
array_1 << fm4
array_1 << fm5


array_1.each do |p| #Trying to print out the name and status values for each instance.
  puts "#{p.name} is #{p.status}"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you ended each instance creation line in your code with `,`. That's why `fm1` is actually created as an array instead of a `FamilyMember`

```
fm1.class
# => Array
```

simply remove the `,` at the end of lines:

```
fm1 = FamilyMember.new('Scott', 18 , 'Male', 'Employed', 'America')
fm2 = FamilyMember.new('Stephen', 30, 'Male', 'Employed', 'Ireland')
fm3 = FamilyMember.new('Gillian', 50, 'Female', 'Employed', 'Ireland')
fm4 = FamilyMember.new('Rolf', 56, 'Male', 'Employed', 'Ireland')
fm5 = FamilyMember.new('Shane', 14, 'Male', 'Unemployed', 'Ireland')
```

and try again:

```
array_1 = Array.new
array_1 << fm1
array_1 << fm2
array_1 << fm3
array_1 << fm4
array_1 << fm5


array_1.each do |p|
  puts "#{p.name} is #{p.status}"
end
```

Output:

```
Scott is Employed
Stephen is Employed
Gillian is Employed
Rolf is Employed
Shane is Unemployed
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I was trying to create the array like this.... array_1 =                                                             [ fm1 = Familymember.new('Scott', 18, 'Male', 'Employed', 'America'),     fm2 = Familymember.new('Stephen', 18, 'Male', 'Employed', 'Ireland')     etc etc ] I must have left the , in. Thanks again